# Extract substring from filename in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a directory full of files that have date strings as part of the filenames:

```
file_type_1_20140722_foo.txt
file_type_two_20140723_bar.txt
filetypethree20140724qux.txt
```

I need to get these date strings from the filenames and save them in an array:

```
['20140722', '20140723', '20140724']
```

But they can appear at various places in the filename, so I can't just use substring notation and extract it directly. In the past, the way I've done something similar to this in Bash is like so:

```
date=$(echo $file | egrep -o '[[:digit:]]{8}' | head -n1)
```

But [I can't use Bash for this because it sucks at math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538909/efficiently-computing-floating-point-arithmetic-hundreds-of-thousands-of-times-i) (I need to be able to add and subtract floating point numbers). I've tried `glob.glob()` and `re.match()`, but both return empty sets:

```
>>> dates = [file for file in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if re.match("[0-9]{8}", file)]
>>> print dates
>>> []
```

I know the problem is it's looking for complete file names that are eight digits long, but I have no idea how to make it look for substrings instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `re.search` instead of `match`, and put the digits inside parentheses to get a match group.

Comment: Would using the split() function be a valid option for you?

Comment: @Batman no, because the numbers are sometimes offset by underscores, and sometimes jammed up next to text.

Comment: @TomZych that doesn't give the substring, just the files that have that substring matching the pattern (all of them).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> import os
>>> [date for file in os.listdir('.') for date in re.findall("(\d{8})", file)]
['20140722', '20140723']
```

Note that if a filename has a 9-digit substring, then only the first 8 digits will be matched. If a filename contains a 16-digit substring, there will be 2 non-overlapping matches.

Comment: Just a note to newcomers to Python... make sure you import the regular expressions engine with `import re`. :) I couldn't upvote because I exhausted my daily vote limit. hehehe

Comment: @LenielMacaferi: Thanks for the improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression looks good, but you should be using re.search instead of re.match so that it will search for that expression anywhere in the string:

```
import re
r = re.compile("[0-9]{8}")
m = r.search(filename)
if m:
    print m.group(0)
```

Comment: This gives the full file name, not the stubstrings

Comment: I missed the group() part, my bad

Answer (score 1):

`re.match` matches from the beginning of the string. `re.search` matches the pattern anywhere.
Or you can try this:

```
extract_dates = re.compile("[0-9]{8}").findall
dates = [dates[0] for dates in sorted(
    extract_dates(filename) for filename in os.listdir('.')) if dates]
```