# How to Extract A String of the Suffix from Folder Names in a Directory? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a directory full of non-empty directories, all with the same prefix, but different numbers at the end. E.g.

```
ABCDE_0003
ABCDE_0005
ABCDE_0007
ABCDE_0009
ABCDE_0011
```

I would like to extract the number at the end of these directory names, excluding the 0's, into a list from which I can call the indices (numbers) for other automated purposes:

```
[3,5,7,9,11]
```

I have tried searching for solutions to this and have found that others have done this for file names, but not directories such as in this thread:

[Extract substring from filename in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895278/extract-substring-from-filename-in-python)

Perhaps there are similar methods to those mentioned in the above thread. I contemplated that a plausible solution could be to have a script convert the directory names into strings, and then it may be easier to extract the number prefixes that way, but I have not found how to do that either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

all_list = os.listdir('.')
numbers = list(
    map(lambda x: int(x[6:]), filter(lambda x: os.path.isdir(x) and x.startswith("ABCDE_"), all_list))
)
# python3
print(numbers)
# python2
print numbers
```